# Output in read file and sort integers leaves a white space I can't find

Tags: c

My code takes in a text document argument and sorts the integers but when I run testing, it fails a simple white space at the end instead of a `\n` but I figure out how to stop the final number in the array with a new line instead of a space. Here is the code:

```
    /* display values */
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
        printf ("%ld ", sorted[i]);
    }
```

Here is the test result and the issue:

```
Program Output
1: 1 2 3 4 5 5 7 8 9 9 9 10 10 11 11 12 14 17 18 20 20 20 24 24 25 25 26 26 27 27 28 28 29 30 30 30 30 31 33 35 35 36 38 40 40 41 42 42 42 47 47 47 48 48 48 48 50 50 51 52 52 52 54 54 57 57 57 57 57 60 61 61 62 62 62 63 64 66 66 66 67 67 69 70 72 72 73 73 75 77 80 82 83 83 83 84 85 86 87 88 88 88 89 91 92 93 94 94 96 97 97 99 [blank space]

Expected Program Output
1: 1 2 3 4 5 5 7 8 9 9 9 10 10 11 11 12 14 17 18 20 20 20 24 24 25 25 26 26 27 27 28 28 29 30 30 30 30 31 33 35 35 36 38 40 40 41 42 42 42 47 47 47 48 48 48 48 50 50 51 52 52 52 54 54 57 57 57 57 57 60 61 61 62 62 62 63 64 66 66 66 67 67 69 70 72 72 73 73 75 77 80 82 83 83 83 84 85 86 87 88 88 88 89 91 92 93 94 94 96 97 97 99
2: [new line]
```

I tried putting in a `\n` in `printf ("%ld ", sorted[i]);` after `sorted[i]` but it needs to go at the close of the array and I'm not certain how (or where) to add it with cause more issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* display values */
for (i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
    printf ("%ld ", sorted[i]);
}
```

This outputs a space after each number. If that's not what you want, don't do it. Maybe you want this:

```
/* display values */
if (count > 0)
    printf ("%ld", sorted[0]);
for (i = 1; i < count; i++ ) {
    printf (" %ld", sorted[i]); // space before every number but first
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If one doesn't want to duplicate code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const size_t count = 100;
    size_t i;
    /* display values */
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
        printf ("%s%ld", i ? " " : "", i + 1 /*sorted[i]*/ );
    }
    fputc('\n', stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect it to be slower, but I think the intent of the code is clearer.